# How to handle soap error such as WSDL not found or Server not found in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

How can I do the

1. Handle Soap Error/ Faults using PHP ?
2. Send Error or Fault status to client script ?

Answer (score 0):

On soap client end:

```
try{ 
} catch a SoapFault
```

On server end you can direct all exceptions to SoapFault if you wish...

This tutorial deals with Zend Soap, but should help:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/x-zsoap/

EDIT

here is another discussion on best ways for a Soap Server to handle errors:

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-SOAP-server-what-is-the-best-approach-for-error-exception-handling-td676006.html